# Python Removing Specific Strings From List Leaves Them Left Over?

Tags: python

I'm writing some code, and I want to search through this list and remove all the 1s at the beginning. Once it hits a 0 I want it to stop and that be the new list. Whenever I have 13 total characters it does what I want - `converted = ("1111111011110")` but when I have the full 16, `converted = ("1111111111011110")` it leaves an extra two ones at the beginning.....

Here's my code:

```
converted = ("1111111111011110")
finalL = []
i = 0
for x in converted:
    finalL.append(x)

print(finalL)


for x in finalL:
    if finalL[0] == "1":
        finalL.remove("1")


print(finalL)
```

right now it prints the first list:
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0']

but then this list: ['1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0']

I want the second print to print ['0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0']

Comment: You shouldn't alter a list you're iterating over. Rather create a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have onces and zeros, and you only care for the string from the first zero and beyond, I would do something like the following.

```
string = '1111111110111111110'
first_zero = string.find('0')
new_string = string[first_zero:] #'0111111110'
```

Note that this will not work for strings with only ones because `find` will return `-1`, which will be the last character of your string. So you would need to make sure that every time a -1 is returned your string is nothing actually.

Or by following your example with loops:

```
converted = '1111111110111111110'
finalL = ''

for i,elem in enumerate(converted):
    if elem=='0':
        # if a zero is found, copy the whole string from
        # this position
        finalL = converted[i:]
        break
```

Comment: use str.index and you avoid the -1 edge case and get an exception, which might be less likely to lead to a bug